# OpenStreetMap shp layer is shifting

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, openstreetmap, wms

I am dealing with this issue more than 2 month and i am hoping that some one have a lead for me.
I am using Openlayers to show some vectors layers like buildings, points, gardens and more layers that i got from the government data, and i got shp file of all the streets from OpenStreetMap.
I want to show everything together so the streets will suite to all the other vector layers.
I am using Geoserver to show all the layers with WMS, my layers projection is ITM (Israel) and the OpenStreetMap layers is the google projection.
when i show everything together the street layers is shifting little bit and its look like this:
[image: It is not suite]
as you can see the layers are not as it should be... and its happening also with the others layers from openstreetmap like buildings etc.
I searched all over the internet and i didnt found solution... hope some one will help me...

Comment: Your overlay layer needs to be ideally in the same projection, or atleast in a projection which uses WGS84 as the datum.

Comment: Or, as an alternative, check the TOWGS84 params of your projection and eventually override them with a value that is more accurate for your area http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/advanced/crshandling/customcrs.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried change the projection of the overlay layer to google projection and its did not help, and how can i know what should be the TOWGS84 params?